# NodeJS unable to addToSet in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to update a field in my JSON which is an array with an element (simple, eh?).
 I want to add `userid` to the `reportedUsersIDs` array.
The query I'm running (via POSTMAN):
http://localhost:3000/api/listing/myStreet/1/1/addReportedUser/564b343fbc2d4310156c6bf9/5671a8f694745bfce5bf6ecf

I checked both ID's exist in the DB and the listing itself exists as well (on street = myStreet, buildingNumber = 1, apartmentNumber = 1).
The code in `routes.js` is:

```
app.put('/api/listing/:street/:buildingNumber/:apartmentNumber/addReportedUser/:userid/:listingid', function (req, res) {

    var listingToUpdate = req.params.listingid;
    var idToAdd = req.params.userid;
    Listing.update({_id: ObjectId(listingToUpdate)},
        {$addToSet: {reportedUsersIDs: ObjectId(idToAdd)}}
        , function (err, listing) {
            if (err) {
                res.send("There was a problem adding the reportedUserID to the listing" + err);
            }
            else {
                console.log("Success adding reportedUserID to listing!");
                res.json(listing);
            }
        })
});
```

And it returns successful but the JSON remains unchanged.

Relevant data:

Schema of the listing I am trying to change:

```
var listingSchema = new Schema({
        street          : String,
        buildingNumber  : Number,
        apartmentNumber : Number,
        reportedUsersIDs: [String]
});
```

And my user schema:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    local            : {
        email        : String,
        password     : String
    },
    name             : String
});
```

Why is my JSON not being updated?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `Model.update()` doesn't return a document, so what exactly is `listing`?

Comment: It doesn't really matter to me if i get listing back or not (or what Model.update() returns to that matter), but please if you have any advice i'd love to hear! :)

Comment: Since `reportedUsersIDs` is an array of `String`, try not to convert it to an `ObjectId` when you try to add it.

Comment: @robertklep thanks! Your solution worked =] If you want, post it as an answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `reportedUsersIDs` is declared in your schema as an array of `String`, you should add them as strings too, instead of as `ObjectId`:

```
{ $addToSet : { reportedUsersIDs : idToAdd } }
```

Alternatively, you can change your schema so it's an array of `ObjectId`:

```
reportedUsersIDs : [ Schema.Types.ObjectId ]
```